# Confusion in checkbox in PHP dynamic values

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a input in a form

```
<form name="frmAdd" method="POST" action="/index.php?a=save">
Status : <input type="checkbox" id="status" name="chkActive" value="" ><label for="status">Active</label>
</form>
```

but when I am calling the value of it, via $_POST['chkActive'], it's giving same value on that page. Whether I have checked the value or not.

Please tell me how can I know that this checkbox is checked or not (in PHP).

Comment: i think you need to give value to checkbox like this: **<input type="checkbox" id="status" name="chkActive" value="1" >**

Comment: `isset($_POST['chkActive'])`? True if it is check, false if it's not.

Comment: @dqlopez but you need to add the `value="x"` attribute to the `input`

Comment: Yes exactly, forgot to include it. I went straight-forward regarding his question on _how can I know that this checkbox is checked or not_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using just a single checkbox you can do this :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="status" name="chkActive" value="1" >
```

within PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['chkActive'])) {
   //its checked
}
```

but you need to ensure there is a value set within the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="frmAdd" method="POST" action="/index.php?a=save">
  Status : <input type="checkbox" id="status" name="chkActive" value="1" ><label      for="status">Active</label>
</form>

<?php if($_POST['chkActive']=='1'){
  echo "is Active";
}else{
  echo "not Active";
}
```

Checkbox only passes the value if is checked.

Comment: you'd want to check if the `$_POST['chkActive']` is actually set then, otherwise you'll get an `E_NOTICE`

Answer (score 0):

to clarify how it works.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="status" name="chkActive"
```

if the checkbox not ticked (checked by user) nothing sent to server. "chkActive" will not exist. So we use isset() to check it.